# Angular - Can't resolve all parameters for VehicleHTTPService

Tags: angular

I have an http service. That has two dependencies in it. I provide the dependencies in the provider array of appModule and import the HttpClientModule too. But i am getting this error on loading phase of the page. I tried everything, changed the orders but nothing worked. My code is like this.

the app Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import HomeComponent from './ngComponents/home/home.component';
import VehicleModule from './ngComponents/vehicle/vehicle.module';
import DataTableComponent from './uiComponents/datatable/datatable.component';
import AppConfigService from './services/appConfig.service';
import VehicleHTTPService from './services/http/vehicleHTTP.service';

@NgModule({

    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, VehicleModule],
    providers: [AppConfigService, VehicleHTTPService],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, HomeComponent, DataTableComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

VehicleHttpService

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import VehicleModel from "../../models/vehicle.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import AppConfigService from "../appConfig.service";
import PagedResult from "../../uiComponents/datatable/types/pagedResult";

@Injectable()
export default class VehicleHTTPService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private appConfigService: AppConfigService) { }

    getPaged(current, take): Observable<PagedResult<VehicleModel>> {

        return this.http
            .post<PagedResult<VehicleModel>>(this.appConfigService.apiRoot + "/vehicle/paged", { observe: "body" });
    }
}
```

AppConfig Service

```
export default class AppConfigService {

    public apiRoot = '/api';
}
```

VehicleModule

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { VehicleRoutingModule } from "./vehicle.routing.module";
import VehicleListComponent from "./vehicleList/vehicleList.component";
import VehicleComponent from "./vehicle.component";
import VehicleFormComponent from "./vehicleForm/vehicleForm.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [VehicleRoutingModule],
    declarations: [VehicleListComponent, VehicleFormComponent, VehicleComponent]

})
export default class VehicleModule {

}
```

VehicleListComponent

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import PagedResult from "../../../uiComponents/datatable/types/pagedResult";
import VehicleModel from "../../../models/vehicle.model";
import VehicleHTTPService from "../../../services/http/vehicleHTTP.service";


@Component({
    selector: 'vehicleList',
    templateUrl: './vehicleList.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./vehicleList.component.css']
})
export default class VehicleListComponent {


    public vehicleData: PagedResult<VehicleModel>;

    constructor(private vehicleHTTPService: VehicleHTTPService) {


        vehicleHTTPService.getPaged(0, 100).subscribe(result => {

        });

    }
}
```

And the error is

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for VehicleHTTPService: (?, ?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15700)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15535)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js:15515)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15875)
    at compiler.js:15786
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15746)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15314)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34405)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:485
CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata @ compiler.js:15700
CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata @ compiler.js:15535
CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata @ compiler.js:15515
CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata @ compiler.js:15875
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:15786
CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata @ compiler.js:15746
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:15314
JitCompiler._loadModules @ compiler.js:34405
JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:34366
JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:34260
CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:239
PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:5563
(anonymous) @ main.ts:8
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 61b12a72aaf8f2b24c40:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 61b12a72aaf8f2b24c40:62
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 61b12a72aaf8f2b24c40:62
```

You can access the project from this repo: https://github.com/aliemre1990/dokuzisik-mean

Comment: Please add the full error log

Comment: My guess is that this is caused by the default attribute on the classes, try removing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on angular cli. I mean at least i dont get the same error but getting different error. Just changed a thing. Transfered DataTableComponent to VehicleModule declarations from AppModule declarations and it worked with different error. The problem is about the project workflow i created i think, because its not angular-cli project. I will change the orders of dependencies maybe its about that.

Edit: Found the solution. When i was reading angular documentation saw this

```
TypeScript normally discards parameter type information when it transpiles the code to JavaScript. It preserves this information if the class has a decorator and the emitDecoratorMetadata compiler option is set true in TypeScript's tsconfig.json configuration file, .
```

I set the emitDecoratorMetadata option in the tsconfig file to true and it worked. Thanks everyone for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when your `VehicleHTTPService` is injected it does not have an idea of the class `AppConfigService` to inject. 
you can either add a `@Injectable()` to your `AppConfigService`

or Remove the

```
private appConfigService: AppConfigService
```

from the `VehicleHTTPService`

put that in the environment.ts file

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
   apiRoot: '/api';

};
```

dont forget to put the production version of the `apiRoot` in the `envirenment.prod.ts`

then you can use it this way

```
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import VehicleModel from "../../models/vehicle.model";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import AppConfigService from "../appConfig.service";
import PagedResult from "../../uiComponents/datatable/types/pagedResult";

@Injectable()
export default class VehicleHTTPService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getPaged(current, take): Observable<PagedResult<VehicleModel>> {

        return this.http
            .post<PagedResult<VehicleModel>>(environment.apiRoot + "/vehicle/paged", { observe: "body" });
    }
}
```

Comment: which of them, adding the @Injectable() or the environments

Comment: Adding injectiable, and removing the appConfigService from the constructor both.

Comment: Yea same error but this time with one question mark in parameters list. I think it cant inject HttpClient too.

Comment: you should be able to, once the module is declared in the imports